# Pentaho, How to transform int to string value

Tags: pentaho, etl

i have question, with Pentaho data integration. I have in one table for example => Police force and values for this are 1,2,3 (Foreign keys). Now question is how to change this values => 1 = No Force, 2 = Force, 3 = Don't know?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ["Value mapper" step](https://wiki.pentaho.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=1050776#content/view/8292143)

1. Add a new "Value mapper" step after your input and create a hop from your input to the "Value mapper" step
2. Double click on the new step to edit it
3. On the "Fieldname to use" select your integer field
4. On the "Target field name" insert a name for the new field that will contain the translated values.
5. Populate the "Field values" table with the list of values to be translated. In your case, for example, in "Source value" you should have "1" (without the parentheses) and in the "Target value" it should be "No Force". Fill the list with your 3 items.

Comment: Sure, btw, i have one more question. Can i do with penthao this (Similar problem than previous): i have in fact table City and values for this from 1-255, and in another table i have descriptions for this number so for example ID_City, City_Name. How can i "merge" this together, (to change in fact table numbers for real city names? Without writing 1 = Graz, 2 = London and so on.. ?

Comment: In that scenario you can use "Database lookup" step, wich allows you to search for a key inside a table and return different fields related to it.